# How to make loop for Azure locks using terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I was trying to apply locks to all of my resource groups in my azure environment. Some resource groups will have read-only locks, some will have delete locks and some won't at all will have locks(means terraform block should not get executed).

I have tried written below code(I know I bad at it cause struggling to find the solution so given some code what I have tried). Requirement is we need to have only one terraform resource block. So, How can I achieve deploy locks to all resource groups under conditions mentioned in 1st paragraph?

We can use modules, count, for each. Scope should be inline with resouregroupbool, For example, when resource block execute with variable "deploy_network_rg_lock" then it should match with "resource id of network resource group". But I need to declare variable for scope but I didn't get it how it can inline with resourcegroupbool.

Could anyone please try to look for it?

```
#resource block for lock
resource "azurerm_management_lock" "locks" {
  count     = var.resourcegroupbool ? 1 : 0  #here also I want to use variables, currently shown is bool and need to have group of boolean        
  name      = var.env == "dev" ? "Read-lock" : "Delete-lock"  
  scope     = #here I want to use variables based on resource group but I didn't get it
  lock_type = var.env == "dev" ? "ReadOnly" : "CanNotDelete"
}
```

```
#varibles I declared
variable "resourcegroupbool" {
  description = "List of resource group whether need to apply lock"
  type = object({
    deploy_network_rg_lock     = bool
    deploy_liveadls_rg_lock    = bool
    deploy_privatelink_rg_lock = bool
    deploy_keyvault_rg_lock    = bool
  })
}

variable "env" {
  type = "string"
  description = "Environment of lock needs to be applied"
```

```
#Varible values in .tfvars
resourcegroupbool = {
  #If true, lock will be applied. If false, lock will be removed if it's exists.
   deploy_network_rg_lock     = false   
   deploy_liveadls_rg_lock    = true   
   deploy_privatelink_rg_lock = true   
   deploy_keyvault_rg_lock    = true   
}

env = "dev"
```

Comment: It's really unclear what you want to achieve. Under what circumstances does this resource have to be created? For all values defined in the `resourcegroupbool` variable? Can you add that variable along with values to the question?

Comment: Hi Marko, Thanks for looking for this. I have modified question for better understanding.

Comment: Great. So this needs to happen for every value from the `resourcegroupbool` variable?

Comment: Yes, Correct. Need to run every value from "resourcegroupbool" and respective resource group ID in scope should be mapped.

Comment: The scope is related to a particular resource group? And the resource group is somehow related to the `resourcegroupbool`?

Comment: Yes, In fact, if network resource group bool is true then it should include network resource group ID as scope.  If false, it should not execute the block for network resource group and go for next run.

Comment: Yes, Correct. Could you please provide some suggestions? Hope you understand the question now.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, it looks like the requirement is to have a variable defining which resource groups should be subject to a lock.

Instead of defining an object variable `resourcegroupbool` with a boolean field for each resource group, why don't you use a variable that contains the names of the resource groups you want to be locked?

The variable could be:

```
variable "locked_resource_groups" {
  type        = set(string)
  description = "Name of the resource groups to which apply a lock"
}
```

Then you can use a data source for fetching the ID of each resource group as follows:

```
data "azurerm_resource_group" "locked" {
  for_each = var.locked_resource_groups

  name = each.value
}
```

Finally, you can use a `for_each` for iterating over the data source and creating the lock on each resource group:

```
resource "azurerm_management_lock" "locks" {
  for_each = data.azurerm_resource_group.locked

  name      = var.env == "dev" ? "Read-lock" : "Delete-lock"
  scope     = each.value.id
  lock_type = var.env == "dev" ? "ReadOnly" : "CanNotDelete"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Telem for looking into this. To be fair, for locks obviously we will need to remove and add them when required. I am looking for that action. To give you a better show, I've included bool for that, If true lock will be applied or will stay, If false, lock won't be applied or removed it exists. I need this scenario to be applied in your above code. Could you please guide how it can be achieved in your above code?

Comment: Hi Akash, I think you can achieve what you are looking for just by including or not the resource groups in the variable `locked_resource_groups`: putting the name of a resource group in that list will create a lock on it while removing it will delete the lock. This of course assumes all your locks are managed through Terraform, otherwise I cannot think of any solution other than importing the existing lock resources into Terraform state.

Comment: Hi Telem, Thanks a lot. Yes, this should work. I was thinking in complex way. I am closing this as I tested successfully.

(May need in future, how the code looks like if I need read locks for one RG and delete for another in the same above your code? I will look for it)